# Get some properties of a Model with JsonView or Dozer-Mapper in SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, gson, dozer

I have some Models that hierarchy depending to each other, In other words, `User` model has a property with type of `Personnel` Model, `Personnel` Model has a property with type of `OrganizationStructure` and so on. like below:

> User > Personnel > OrganizationStructure > OrganizationType

for security & performance concerns, I want to select some property to return as `json` Format with **Spring MVC REST**; So I use `@JsonView` and put this annotation on properties that I want returned.

According to [this tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring), I use from this annotation, something like below:
class for JsonView:

```
public class View {
     public interface Summary {}
     public interface SummaryWithRecipients extends Summary {}
}
```

view model for OrganizationStructure:

```
public class OrganizationStructureViewModel extends BaseEntityViewModel<Long> {
     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
     private String                title;
     private String                description;
     @JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
     private Set<UserViewModel>    users;
}
```

and view model for Personnel:

```
 public class PersonnelViewModel extends BaseEntityViewModel<Long> {
         @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
         private String      username;
         @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
         private String      firstname;
         @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
         private String      lastname;
         private String      email;
         private String      password;
    }
```

But I don't want to put `@JsonView` to inner Models (like `OrganizationStructure` & `OrganizationType` models), Because I have no Direct access to These Models to put `@JsonView` on their properties. In other hand, These Models are very use in my project and for every view I had to put separate `@JsonView` to them and number of annotation on properties of these models are too HIGH.

- One Solution is using of **Dozer-Mapper** and describe expected properties in `xml file` and use `ModelView`, But many properties of `ModelView` is almost Duplicate of Domain Model. Here is my Dozer-Mapper XML configuration:
  Dozer-Mapper XML configuration for Personnel:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <mappings xmlns="...">
      <mapping>
          <class-a>org.somepackages.personnel.Personnel</class-a>
          <class-b>org.somepackages.personnel.PersonnelViewModel</class-b>
          <!-- Here is some fileds that I want to map from model to view model -->
      </mapping>
  </mappings>`

and Dozer-Mapper XML configuration for OrganizationStructure is look like Personnel.
Is any solution that only describe expected property in one place and use it? some things like Dozer-Mapper without `ViewModel`, or `@JsonView` with on probably one master model (in my case, `User` Model)?